# git status shows unexisting untracked file

Tags: linux, git, shell

I don't know if this question should be moved to ServerFault or it belongs here!

Working on a remote Unix server, I created a file `file_x.php` using `FileZilla`.

I'm using `GIT` on the terminal.

When I do `git status`, it shows me this :

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  some_other_file1.php
  some_other_file2.php
   file_x.php
  ^
  |__ Note this weird blank space
```

**The problem :** I wanted to delete this file, I tried from `FileZilla` but this didn't work, it shows me `there is no such file or directory` ! But the file is always there!

So I tried :

```
rm -rf file_x.php       # This didn't work
sudo rm -rf  file_x.php # I'm not from the sudoers
git checkout file_x.php # This didn't do a thing !
git clear -f            # This didn't do a thing !
git rm file_x.php
==> fatal: pathspec 'file_x.php' did not match any files
```

My question, what does this mean ? and how do I remove this file ?

Comment: That "weird" blank space is not weird at all. It is part of the file name. If it is a regular white space then you can wrap the file name (including the leading space) into quotes (`"`) or apostrophes (`'`) every time you put it into a command line (any command line). F.e. `git rm " file_x.php"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the space:

```
rm \ file_x.php
```

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui, check mark this answer if this solved your problem, this is the most efficient way to thank somebody on StackOverflow

Comment: @DudeCoder, hahaha yes I know, just I had to wait for 7 min :P